# Zoom in a Forced Directed Chart in Amcharts 5?

Tags: javascript, zooming, hierarchy, treemap, amcharts5

Is there an equivalent Amcharts4 option to:

chart.zoomable = true

in Amcharts5 for a Forced Directed or a Treemap Grapth (Hierarchy Graphs)?

An option for Amcharts5 to make a Hierarchy Graph zoomable.

My code is like this:

```
  var container = root.container.children.push(
    am5.Container.new(root, {
    width: am5.percent(100),
    height: am5.percent(100),
    layout: root.verticalLayout
    })
  );

  var series = container.children.push(
    am5hierarchy.ForceDirected.new(root, {
    downDepth: 1,
    initialDepth: config.initialDepth,
    topDepth: 1,
    valueField: "value",
    categoryField: "name",
    childDataField: "children",
    linkWithField: "link",
    minRadius: config.minRadio,
    maxRadius: config.maxRadio,
    tooltip: tooltip
    })
  );
```